# How to use NSURLConnection completionHandler with swift

Tags: block, nsurlconnection, swift

Does anybody know how handlers (blocks) work in swift? I am trying to get this code running but i can't find any documentation of the right syntax for the completionHandler.

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"some url")
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request:request, queue:queue, completionHandler handler:((NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Like this:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ response, data, error in /* Your code */ })
```

Or more verbose variant.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    /* Your code */
})
```

Comment: Can anyone help me understand how to get data out of the NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest? The completionHandler requires a void return value, so I am not certain how to get my request data out of the completionHandler. thanks!

Comment: You have access for example to the other variables into the function where you call the class method sendAsynchronousRequest, e.g.,         var lol: String! = "a"
        
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            /* Your code */
            lol = "b"
        })

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this code:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request,queue:queue,completionHandler:{response,data,error in /* code goes here */ })
```

For more info, you can refer to [this](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-tutorial-part-2/) tutorial, or or check the answers to [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift/24013547#24013547).

Answer (score 3):

`sendAsynchronousRequest` has been deprecated in newer versions of Swift. Move to `dataTaskWithRequest`, luckily it is used pretty much the same way

```
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"http://YOUR_DESIRED_URL.com")!)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

});

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

The right term you are looking for here is ***Closure***. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks in C and Objective-C. In addition to Tomáš's answer there is another short version to use the completion handler here:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler: {$0; $1; $2})
```

Here I have used *Shorthand Argument Names*. I am accessing *response* as **$0**, *data* as **$1** and *error* as **$3**. I find this syntax more easy to read and write unless the parameters are large in number otherwise the code will become unreadable.