# Syntax for passing “no options” to a parameter of type NSJSONWritingOptions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift

In Objective-C I wrote code like the following:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:someDictionary
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
```

I am trying to do the same thing in Swift. With some prompting from Xcode’s syntax checking I wrote it like this:

```
var jsonError: NSError
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(someDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(), error: &jsonError)
```

but this gives me an error: “Could not find an overload for `init` that accepts the supplied arguments.” I think the problem might be with the `NSJSONWritingOptions()` bit, and I’m guessing I just have the Swift syntax wrong. I tried replacing `NSJSONWritingOptions()` with `NSJSONWritingOptions(0)` and got the same error; I tried replacing it with `nil` (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24013852/371228)) but I got the error “Could not find an overload for `__conversion` that accepts the supplied arguments.”

How can I indicate that I want the default JSON writing options, whatever those might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the NSJSONWritingOptions; the type of error you're passing should be `NSError?`, not `NSError`.

Comment: \*sigh\* That fixed it, thanks. I hope they’ll be able to add a little more information to the error messages before the final release!

Comment: Yeah, the errors are definitely a place that could use some work.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for the Swift 4.2 equivalent, the `options` parameter is now optional:

```
var jsonData:Data?
do {
    jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: someDictionary)
} catch let parsingError {
    print(parsingError)
}
```

Or if you are 100% sure `dataWithJSONObject` will succeed:

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:someDictionary)
```

Comment: In Swift 3+ *no options* is the default so the recommended way is to **omit** the parameter `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:someDictionary)`

Answer (score 0):

Nicer way with swift will be:

```
let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])
```

to pass empty array...

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33016014/1787109)

Comment: *Nicest* way is `let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values)`