# Use NSSerialization.datawithJSON in Swift 2

Tags: swift2, nsjsonserialization

Been trying to get this to work in Swift 2.0, the error says:

> Type NSJSONWritingOptions cannot conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible

at `var options = prettyPrinted...`:

```
func JSONStringify(value: AnyObject,prettyPrinted:Bool = false) -> String {

    var options = prettyPrinted ? NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted : nil

    if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) {
        do{
            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(value, options: options)
            if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                return string as String
            }
        } catch {

        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
let options = prettyPrinted ? 
         NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted : NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0)
```

is the right syntax for swift 2.0

Answer (score 5):

You can also pass an empty array for no options:

```
let options:NSJSONWritingOptions = prettyPrinted ? .PrettyPrinted : []
```