# I got an error swift on xcode7.

Tags: swift, xcode7

That error tells me that "Result value in ‘?’ :’ expression have mismatching types ’NSJONWritingOptions’ and ‘_'". Does anyone know how to fix this? I wrote these codes on xcode6.3.1 and converted to xcode7 just now. worked on xcode6 though....

```
public func toString(pretty:Bool=false)->String {
    switch _value {
    case is NSError: return "\(_value)"
    case is NSNull: return "null"
    case let o as NSNumber:
        switch String.fromCString(o.objCType)! {
        case "c", "C":
            return o.boolValue.description
        case "q", "l", "i", "s":
            return o.longLongValue.description
        case "Q", "L", "I", "S":
            return o.unsignedLongLongValue.description
        default:
            switch o.doubleValue {
            case 0.0/0.0:   return "0.0/0.0"    // NaN
            case -1.0/0.0:  return "-1.0/0.0"   // -infinity
            case +1.0/0.0:  return "+1.0/0.0"   //  infinity
            default:
                return o.doubleValue.description
            }
        }
    case let o as NSString:
        return o.debugDescription
    default:
        let opts = pretty
           //below is the code I got an error for
            ? NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted : nil
        if let data = (try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
            _value, options:opts)) as NSData? {
                if let result = NSString(
                    data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                    ) as? String {
                        return result
                }
        }
        return "YOU ARE NOT SUPPOSED TO SEE THIS!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use NSSerialization.datawithJSON in Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920766/use-nsserialization-datawithjson-in-swift-2)

Answer (score 1):

`options` in `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject:options:` should be an empty array if you don't want to specify any options. So your code should look like this:

```
let opts = pretty ? NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted : []
```

Previously it expected `nil`, but there was change in the way iOS SDK is mapped in Swift.

Comment: @stack0101 I see you are new at SO. If you find some answer helpful, you should mark it as accepted. It will help people, who might have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my Swift 2.0 implementations-

```
let options = prettyPrinted ? 
         NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted : NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0)
```