# Can i create a custom keyboard component to be installed in iphone settings?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I Want to create a custom keyboard component(sharing images via keyboard not numbers or decimals) so that the user can download that in iPhone and select it to be used in any app like we do from the iPhone settings to change the keyboard or add a new keyboard.

Comment: Yes, that is called `App Extensions` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1 But to create an `App Extension` you need to create an App first for the extension, then you can use it like other keyboards.

Comment: You have to do some RND before asking question related. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 Custom Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340061/ios-8-custom-keyboard)