# Parsing data in Swift - issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing the XML data as the following and it is working in objective-C (I can show the objective-C code if needed.

```
//Update

//NSData
    response = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kalkatawi.com/jsonTest.php"]];

if(response!=nil) {

NSError *parseError = nil;

jsonArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<[jsonArray count];i++)
{
    NSString  * city = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"city"];

    [jsonArray1 addObject:city];

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray1);
}
```

My web result:

```
<city>1</city><city>2</city><city>3</city>
```

I have read this topic about [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift) but I am getting an issue that `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"` in the `jsonData` line. So please where would be my issue?

My code:

```
    let urlPath = "http://example.net/example/example.php"

    //Crash happens here
    let jsonData: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(urlPath, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)

    let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    for parseData in jsonDict {

        println(parseData)
    }
```

Comment: json? this looks like xml to me ..

Comment: Thanks for the notice Sorry I have edited my question @meda

Comment: You can't parse XML with `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: I thought I can while I am calling it in the objective-C as `[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/est.php"]];` @Jesper

Comment: No, you can't. Please show the working objective-C code and an actual example of the data you're getting back, something is off here.

Comment: @jrturton I provided my code please check

Comment: Anyway guys I made a mistake and I am changing my code XML to JSON. Thanks for all you response and I am sorry again for that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It looks like Apple has not implemented NSXMLDocument in Swift yet. Here is a library that might help you with parsing XML in Swift: https://github.com/ndavidsson/NDHpple

If it were implemented, this is how you would do it:

```
let urlPath:NSURL = NSURL(scheme:"http", host:"example.net", path:"example/example.php")
var error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
var xml:NSXMLDocument = NSXMLDocument(contentsOfUrl: urlPath, error: error!)
```

At that point, xml will represent an NSXMLDocument. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working again crashing the same place.

Comment: Wait, sorry, i just noticed your update. You're trying to parse XML?

Comment: Sorry yes, I am trying to parse xml.

Comment: NSXMLDocument is undeclared type? I have wrote delegate `NSXMLParserDelegate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59510/discussion-between-can-and-tom-alexander).