# What is the best approach to make a simple json parser with swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Just to understand the basics of json parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Things I would give a try:

1. Here someone has an answer for parsing JSON with Swift: [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift)
2. Check this tutorial: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-tutorial-part-2/
3. See what others have done; you can check GitHub to find JSON parsers (example: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/). Then rewrite it in Swift.

Best wishes!