# Why is retrieving the data from this URL returning nil?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am following [this post for getting JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift) and for some reason this function:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData {
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}
```

returns `nil` as I get the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have broken up the function:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData {
    let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlToRequest)
    let data : NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    return data
}
```

And according to my debugger:

```
Printing description of url:
www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/.json
Printing description of data:
(NSData!) data = nil
```

Pasting in the URL to Chrome doesn't give a blank page. It gives a massive glob of JSON, so I am confused why `data` is nil?

Comment: Use the version of the function which returns you error information

Comment: www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/.json - I wouldn't expect any data from the URL. And you have written your code to crash if there is no data.

Comment: You forgot to add the url scheme. try using "h t t p://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/.json"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, the major issue was the url scheme, I thought it was implicit. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the url scheme. NSURL needs the full address. You should also use if let to safely unwrap your optional data:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData? {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlToRequest) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            return data
        }
    }
    return nil
}

if let myData = getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/.json") {
    println("there is data")   // "there is data in myData"
}
```