# Strange error in Xcode 7 resource load is insecure

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am getting an error since Xcode 7 that seems very new. I am trying to load a video from a link and it works on the app store app (built with Xcode 6 and Swift 1.2) but now since I updated I receive this error:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

I did a search and tried changing the info.plist file to add

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
```

but this did not help. Any idea what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody is interested. I was able to solve this problem by using the secure version of my site. It looks like there might be a way to modify the info.plist file to allow http requests (see [How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file) )  but I am going with https for now.