# Cannot load HTTP links in UIWebView in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9, xcode7, nsapptransportsecurity

I am trying to load HTTP links within UIWebView. The links are from my website so they are reliable. I have searched the internet and found the solution here: [How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

After following that solution my info.plist looks like this.:

[image]

Even after making the changes I cannot load HTTP links within UIWebView. I get the following error:

***App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure***

Is there something I am doing wrong?

***UPDATE:***

After making the changes suggested by Ramshad in comments it still does not work.
See image below:

[image]

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544

Comment: @Ramshad please see update.

Comment: I have the same issue, any update that works?

Comment: @ewindsor have a look at my answer on this question but note that this will allow all connections. But this is the only way I could get it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011558/no-solution-for-transport-security/33011914#33011914

Answer (score 17):

It should be done like this, you need to add in your Plist the following records 
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)

NSAppTransportSecurity <- Type Dictionary

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads <- Type Boolean Value YES

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to add the all thing, without "http://":

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try this, this should fix your issue

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please see my updated question. I have tried this but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check this article: [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-load-http-content-in-wkwebview-and-uiwebview).

> App Transport Security (ATS) normally doesn’t allow our apps to connect to HTTP servers, but there’s a special exception you can add to allow UIWebView and WKWebView to load insecure content.

TL;DR

Just add to your `.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` is available from iOS 9.0 so should be fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misspelled the link or a domain.

I had the same problem and after checking again the domain which was `123.company.othercompany.com`, so I changed `company.com` to `othercompany.com` and it started to load external website.