# No solution for Transport Security?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios9, xcode7, transport-security

I have tried all the methods of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) for solving the problem of: "Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."

But if I try for example adding this in my plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>www.myserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

I get an error:"Unsupported URL", where in this case my link, looks like this:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "www.myserver.com/jsonsignup.php")
```

But if I would use:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.myserver.com/jsonsignup.php")
```

I would get the same error of Transport Security as mentioned above.

Any help?

Comment: Try to remove "www." from your server key in the plist file.

Comment: And how should my link look like, for request?

Comment: Exactly the same as it is now.

Comment: Just remove 'Temporary', the keys are now `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads ` and `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion`

Comment: @ShahzadChaudhry try my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I tried adding it to info.plist but it did not work for me either. So I tried this and it worked.

Click on your project name in the "Project Navigator" then click on info. And add it there. See highlighted.

[image]

**Before I tried selecting the plist from my project navigator under supporting files and for some reason it did not work. The above should work for you.**

[image]

**Note:** This will allow all connections.

Comment: this is not the solution, this can be seen as a hack, you enabled any kind of  http load, putting your users into the risk

Comment: @JulianKról the answer already warns the reader that this will allow all connections. The answers main focus was to show the correct place within xCode where to edit the plist.

Comment: I know that this will work but it shouldn't be seen as a solution, as it disables extra security benefits provided in iOS 9

Comment: The correct way is adding a list of domains that can be visited; see this blog post http://www.soortapp.com/ios-9-nsapptransportsecurity-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `http://`request ? then add following code in your `.plist` file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

I hope it's work for you.