# Swift 2, Xcode 7 .plist issue for NSURLSession HTTP support and URL schemes

Tags: plist, swift2, ios9, xcode7

After new cutting-edge and state-of-the art Apple Xcode and iOS update and 3-hours to Swift 2.0 migrating, i stuck at the following issue. Here is my **.plist** code :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>okauth</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Well, LSApplicationQueriesSchemes enables handling canOpenURL: procedure and NSAppTransportSecurity allows calling non-encrypted HTTP URL's. 
As you can see, my plist syntax equals [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

Unfortunately, non of these settings work - i still cannot connect my server via HTTP and open other apps with custom URL schemes. Did anyone face these problems? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about?  What are those plist entries supposed to do?  What frameworks use them?  Update your title and tags to add that detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

Comment: @EricD. - updated question

Comment: Your "this answer" link points to the question. I linked to it because there's several answers that could help you, notably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31623388/2227743), and as you can see, your plist is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i finally found the problem. Thanks to breathtaking technologies, Xcode doesn't refresh .plist files in .lproj folders, so when i edit .plist from Xcode it's not guranteed, that those files would be changed. Thanks everyone!

***EDIT :***

and finally i found the issue - all these settings are located here :

[image]

While i was editing Info.plist from project navigator!!!((