# How to add NSExceptionDomains to plist of xcode Version 7.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, ios9, xcode7

I would like to bundle a HTML based website as an iPhone app using Xcode Version 7.0.1, everything works fine and my only issue is that when I test the application on iPhone 4s, it wont show images that are accessed through `http`. However, I could access images of another website that provide `https` access to its images.

Is there any way to add http support to the bundle?

**Update**

I added an `NSExceptionDomains` to my plist file, but I still have the same issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My Project</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myproject.names</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>myproject</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main_iPhone</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main_iPad</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>appanalytics.embarcadero.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I also tried following based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>mydomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

**Update**

I added the code mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) but still have the same issue.

**Update**

As suggested, I changed the plist to following but still has the same issue. Also, I added http:// to values of key tags to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My Project</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myproject.names</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.1.6</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>myproject</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.2</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main_iPhone</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main_iPad</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>myproject.com.ca</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>myproject.com.ca</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: please visit : https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/ios9-security-privacy/

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, your Info.plist has two separate NSAppTransportSecurity key-value pairs. You should fix that so there is only the one pair.

Your question doesn’t say what domains your images are loaded from. It would be easier to give a specific answer if you could include this information.

If, for example, your images are loaded from `example.com` or subdomains, you could add an exception as follows:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>appanalytics.embarcadero.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

If you don’t know in advance what domains the images will be loaded from, then you can instead allows HTTP access to all domains:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>appanalytics.embarcadero.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Note that although the inclusion of `appanalytics.embarcadero.com` in this second example is technically redundant, it is recommended that you specify ATS exceptions for all known domains that your app will access.

Comment: thanks, I know domain of the images and added that as you suggested but did not help, I updated the question.

Comment: Looking at your last updated plist—you took my example too literally, as you have included two different entries for `myproject.com.ca` in NSExceptionDomains. You should have only one entry for each domain, with the exceptions needed for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this tutorial on how to configure [App Transport Security](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) or you could just allow everything as before by adding Dictionary "NSAppTransportSecurity" with a Boolean key named "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" with the value "YES" in your info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Your key name is `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` but it should be `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`

Also, did you try to add

```
<key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<false/>
```

to ATS domain's key?
Some domains requires it.