# How to add NSAppTransportSecurity to Cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a ionic cordova project. That application needs to be onfigured App Transport Security Exceptions for iOS 9 version.

Does anyone know how to add below configuration to the cordova project configuration file? (config.xml)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Regards,

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably by using a plugin. Take a look at [cordova-plugin-transport-security](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-transport-security)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-transport-security --save
```

You can see in its plugin.xml file how it modifies the plist value.

```
<platform name="ios">
  <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
      <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
      </dict>
  </config-file>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 7):

Referring to the [Whitelist Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html#ios-whitelisting) this should be done by adding

```
<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />
```

to your config.xml.

Answer (score 4):

You are able to update properties in your app Info.plist file by using the `edit-config` tag directly in your `config.xml`.

This is similar to [Connor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676673/how-to-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-cordova-project/33683927#33683927) but allows for more general control of your app's config.

For this particular case you could include the following (replacing `${APP_NAME}` with the name of your app, unsurprisingly):

```xml
  <edit-config file="${APP_NAME}/${APP_NAME}-Info.plist" target="NSAppTransportSecurity" mode="merge">
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
  </edit-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always done this using a Hook script and plistbuddy.  So I would place this in the hooks folder, making sure it's set to executable file permissions (755 will do):

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "Adjusting plist for App Transport Security exception."
val=$(/usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "add NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains:DOMAIN_TO_SET_AS_EXCEPTION:NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads bool true" platforms/ios/HelloCordova/HelloCordova-Info.plist 2>/dev/null)
echo "Done"
```

Replace "DOMAIN_TO_SET_AS_EXCEPTION" with your domain e.g. myhost.example.com - I'm not a fan of setting all domains open until you need them so recommend a whitelisting approach.

Then to get this to fire I modify config.xml in the iOS platform section to look like:

```
    ...
<platform name="ios">
    <hook type="before_build" src="hooks/ios_ats.sh" />
    ...
```

I wrote a [blog post](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/) showing this along with a complete example project on Github linked from the post that you can get an appropriate script from.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be running on the phone (not server)?

Comment: Yes it's on the phone.  Use a hook script to set it during the scripted cordova build command.  There is no server configuration here not sure what makes you think there is.