# Why is jQuery Ajax not working in Cordova iOS app

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I am building a Cordova app that uses jQuery Ajax to upload images to our server. The uploads were working for a while on both Android and iOS, then after a while they suddenly stopped working on iOS. Now, after a few seconds of trying to access a website, the request fails and I get an error message, which isn't much help. The error is like the following:

```
readyState: 0
status: 0
statusText: "error"
```

My code is:

```
    $.ajax("http://testapi.com/api", {
        data: submission,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        method: "POST",
        // submission was successful
        success(data) {
          if (JSON.parse(data).success) {
            // backend validated and accepted submission
          } else {
            // backend rejected submission due to validation errors
          }
        },
        // submission failed
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        error(xhr, text, error) {
          alert(
            JSON.stringify(xhr) + "  " + text + " " + JSON.stringify(error)
          );
        }
      });
```

My Content Security Policy, in index.html is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * blob: gap://* file: http: https: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * blob: file: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https: ; img-src 'self' data: blob: file: ; media-src * blob: file:  http: https: ;"
```

And config.xml is:
    `

```
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>World Bee Count needs access to your camera and photo library</string>
    </config-file>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" overwrite="true" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" overwrite="true" target="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </edit-config>
    <string file="*-Info.plist" overwrite="true" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </string>
    <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>World Bee Count needs access to your camera and photo library</string>
    </config-file>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2D81C1" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
</platform>
<engine name="ios" spec="5.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" />
<plugin name="com.subitolabs.android.cordova.galleryapi" spec="https://github.com/Collaborne/cordova-gallery-api.git"></plugin>
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera-preview"></plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="~3.0.2" />`

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I am running this on iOS 13 and using PhoneGap build

My problem is most similar to this
[Ajax Not working in IOS 9.0 Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706656/ajax-not-working-in-ios-9-0-cordova)

I tried updating my config.xml according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676673/how-to-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-cordova-project)
But it doesn't seem to be working

Any help is would be very much appreciated, I've been working on this for hours and can't seem to get anywhere

Comment: Having the same issue, did you solve this?

Comment: Yes I did, I will add my solution with code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I found the problem was because of a recent update from UIWebView to WKWebView, which was breaking the Ajax code. I added the  [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr)  plugin to my project as described in the documentation. I also removed the version spec on the WKWebView engine plugin. My config.xml was edited to include the following:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="~2.1.4" />
```

And under

```
<platform name="ios">
....
<preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts" value="on" />
<preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
<preference name="NativeXHRLogging" value="full" />
```

I tried various combinations of the preferences, but only this combination worked. However, NativeXHRLogging could be disabled as it didn't seem to matter. After this everything started working once again

Comment: This seems to not work under cordova-ios 6.1.0 - the WKWebView engine has been integrated and adding file-xhr only tries to bring in the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin, which causes build errors. Any ideas?

Comment: @AaronMason I am also facing the same issue. Build is failing after I add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin.

Comment: @subbu if you're using cordova-ios 6.1.0, the solution is to remove that plugin and add a line like this to your config.xml: `<preference name="scheme" value="myapp" />` then have your backend send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with that URL scheme rather than of http/s.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem. I'm using cordova-ios 6.1.1 and I have removed the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin but ajax still doesn't work... I still get Preflight response is not successful.. Failure to load resource. 

I have tried adding `cordova-plugin-cors` but that doesn't work too.. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when building with Cordova IOS 6.1.1.

I tried above solution but got build errors with -engine as mentioned.

I removed -engine and just used the latest file-xhr and it worked.

Just use the following plugin, worked with or without the above mentioned preferences.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" source="npm" version="3.0.0" />
```