# jQuery Ajax not working in Cordova iOS App

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

We are building Cordova app which uses jQuery AJAX. It was working fine but suddenly stopped working on iOS. It works sometimes but not always.

```
$.ajax({
   url      : "https://example.com/result.php",
   dataType : 'json',
   success  : function(data){
      //
   }
});
```

And the result I get is:

`xhr.status : 0`

I heard that Apple update from UIWebView to WKWebView, which was breaking the Ajax code. After that, I found this answer and tried but still its not working. As i said earlier, its not always working.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61922415/3468603

As per the above answer, included these plugins

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="~2.1.4" />
```

```
<preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts" value="on" />
<preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
<preference name="NativeXHRLogging" value="full" />
```

Can Anyone help?