# App Transport Security Key not working in info.plist

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9, app-transport-security

My info.plist is set as follows:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]
However when loading "www.google.com" into a UIWebView, I still receive an ATS security error:

`The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection`

Comment: Do you have an `NSExceptionDomains` key in your plist?

Comment: Do you close </dict>?

Comment: dict is closed, forgot to paste that line. Also added what it looks like in the plist

Comment: Here is all details related app transport security http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file

Comment: @Lalitkumar I have followed the instructions from that post as documented above, still not luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was actually that the info.plist file was not properly assigned to my target. The key in the Plist was correct. At some point I had divided my app into 2 targets for a lite and pro version, each with their own info.plist, however they were not properly assigned.

This can be checked under`Target > Build Settings > Search for "Info.plist" > Change path under targeting`

Answer (score 0):

The exact value is

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Once you have entered into the plist make sure it is correctly represented in the Project settings info tab

[image]

Comment: It is set correctly as you demonstrated. However in the webview load did fail method I am still receiving that error.