# ionic 5/ Angular 8 - ios unable to connect to local network server

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

the iphone can connect to the testing server, however, with local network providing the IP address 192.168.x.xx:3000 cannot connect with the error `Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.` There is no problem with an Android device connecting but with iOS I receive the error above.

Also, I have changed the DNS manually to what is suggested in other posts to `8.8.8.8` however the issue still remains the same. thanks.

I run the command: `$ ionic cordova run ios --device`

Comment: which command your are running?

Comment: updated post with the command

Comment: already tried this solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279491/a-server-with-the-specified-hostname-could-not-be-found

Comment: I have, as well as all the sub comments

Answer (score 0):

this has something to with on which band you're connected to your wifi. You can resolve this by connecting to the 2.4Ghz band and not the 5Ghz. I still don't know why but it only happens with iOS devices. MacOS is all fine.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194014/5891067). I still yet to find out the reason, though.

I'm also building an ionic app when I encountered this but the same is true for vue3 and python.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and the problem was the windows firewall.

Configuring my app to communicate through the Windows Defender Firewall over `Public` at `Allowed Applications` solved my problem.

View a print at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121615/3199081)