# My session.dataTaskWithRequest method is not returning any data

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, nsurlsession

I need to interrogate our Api to populate our main screen, so I set up a separate class called `RestApiManager` and added the code below:

```
import UIKit

class RestApiManager: NSObject {
   static let sharedInstance = RestApiManager()

   let baseURL = "http://api.randomuser.me/"

   func getData() {
      let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseURL)!)
      let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

      let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if data != nil {
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary      //:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)
            }catch _ as NSError
            {
            }
        } 
    })
    task.resume()
   }
}
```

I used the url shown as a simple test, as I know it returns data without any properties as i tested it in my browser but each time I run my app the data is always nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: response and error is nil?

Comment: what is the response and error?

Comment: `catch _ as NSError {}` does not make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since this is a Http request you need to add NSTransportSecurity in
>   your info.plist. Hope you have done that.

If you haven't done that. Visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

**Also you need to tell the request method i.e. .GET in your case.**

```
let headers = ["cache-control": "no-cache"]

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://api.randomuser.me/")!,
                                        cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    println(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
    println(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

This is working for me and might also work for you.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. My transfer is now working