# Unable to download and view images from parse in iOS

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

As of yesterday I was able to view images fine but now I can't view from url and get error as

> NSErrorFailingURLKey=`http://files.parsetfss.com`

Some images are working fine while others are getting issues.

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objStampData.stampImage.url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) 
{
    if(!error)
    {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

1. Name of the image in parse. There I have problem when the name contains somestrange symbols like ".","&" and etc. Try with simple name and different image format.
2. Check if you allow
       access to parse from the plist file check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

Comment: since yesterday it was working fine I didn't changed anything in parse. all of sudden I got this issue.

Comment: hmm in fact you know that Parse is almost dead in parse.com you can see this message  in July 28, 2016
Finish setting up your self-hosted Parse Server and release a new app pointing to it.

Comment: I have migrated parse to mongodb and heroku server .