# Allow arbitrary loads with Xcode 8

Tags: xcode8, app-transport-security

Is there a way for me to enable Allow Arbitrary Loads with Xcode 8? There no longer seems to be a info.plist option that makes this possible. Plus with the removal of the NSData types its all a little confusing.

Comment: How is the Info.plist related to the programming language or the (NS)Data types?

Comment: I am trying to enable http requests

Comment: In Swift 2 you could just change the plist to allow for arbitrary loads

Comment: You have to edit the Info.plist, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file. That is completely unrelated to used programming language.

Comment: That trick doesn't work in xcode 8 the property you named is NSAppTransportSecurity and NS datatypes are no longer present in Swift 3 which is used with xcode 8

Comment: There are two different views of the info.plist.  The view you are seeing, which is essentially translating the "NS" prefixed keys to more user friendly ones, and the raw data one, which will show you the "NS" keys.  See the note labeled "Important" in this section of Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry buddy.

When you pass the mouse in the plist you will see a plus symbol

[image: screenshot]
Any doubt you just ask here.

Comment: How do you find this in Xcode 8? It isnt in the same place as Xcode 7

Comment: Yes. In the info.plist in your project