# How to Make HTTP Requests In React Native IOS application?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
fetch('http://119.9.52.47:3000/api/countries', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'},
   }).then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseData) => {
           console.log(responseData);
       })
```

Here is my code . But that's not work.

Comment: edited my answer now check it

Comment: In which info.plist file i have to add  App Transport Security exceptions ?
Because more  info.plist files in application folder.

Comment: Search for AppName-Info.plist where AppName is the name of your app.

Comment: That's Not work @Nitesh Mishra , Network Request Failed issue come.

Comment: Have you created a webservice? if not then how would you post the data?

Comment: Now Works @Nitesh Mishra Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try like this for send data to server(POST)

```js
let response = await fetch(
    'http://your_url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.name,//data which u want to send
        password: this.state.password,
      })
  });
  let responseText = await response.text();
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){
    Alert.alert('Server response', responseText)

  }
  else {
    let error = responseText;
    throw error
    //Alert.alert('Login', error)
  }
} catch(errors) {
  Alert.alert('Login', errors)

  Actions.Documents();
}
```

Edit: As latest iOS sdk enforces connection to be in https protocol instead of http.you can add an exception to your domain inside info.plist file of the Xcode project.

if you want to allow everything write this inside info.plist

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>yourdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>
```

for more info check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623388/7604342

Comment: There was a issue in " let responseText = await response.text(); " @Nitesh Mishra

Comment: Error : Syntax Error " await " is the reserved word.

Comment: add this code where you want to call this like you can use it inside button press event. let me know if you get any error?

Comment: Now also return same Error @ Nitesh Mishra
 
Error : Syntax Error " await " is the reserved word.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Refer that Link That's also work -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqXFE.png

Answer (score 4):

You can use normal fetch function, only add you http host into exception. 
In your XCode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Network docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html):

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL. If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http) you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception.

Your request is `http`, so you need to either add the address as an App Transport Security exception in your ios app, or use https.

Comment: How to add the address to App Transport Security exception ?

Could you please briefly explain?  @Moti Azu

Comment: I have the same issue. did you find solution?

Comment: Edit in `Info.plist`