# React native ios http featch method fail

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

How to access the react native ios http featch

```
fetch('http://10.0.2.2:53396/index.cfm/?fwreinit=1', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        body: JSON.stringify({ public_key: "Arunkumar" ,private_key: "cfarun",})
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by 1. using https link for your endpoints 2. Update info.plist file and add 'App Transport Security Settings' -> 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' and set its value to 'YES'.

See attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666142/how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-native-ios-application)

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL. If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http) you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception.

Comment: multiple info.plist files in multiple directories in my React Native app. Any idea which folder contains the correct file to change?