# Network request failed - iOS - React Native 0.72.1

Tags: ios, react-native

I upgraded react native from 0.63.5 to 0.72.1. The application runs ok in Android, I am able to login and make other requests. But when I run the app in iOS, I get [TypeError: Network request failed].

I tried to delete DerivedData, and to install pods again (rm Podfile.lock && pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all && pod install) but it didn't work.

Here's my `Podfile`:

````rb
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

MIN_IOS_OVERRIDE = '14.0'
if Gem::Version.new(MIN_IOS_OVERRIDE) > Gem::Version.new(min_ios_version_supported)
    min_ios_version_supported = MIN_IOS_OVERRIDE
end

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true

prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'PopUp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

   # Add this line to use static frameworks
   use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  
   # Add this line to enable static frameworks for RNFirebase
   $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'PopUpTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
      end
    end
  end
end
````

And my AppDelegate.mm:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  
  self.moduleName = @"PopUp";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

macOS: Monterey v12.6

Xcode: 14.2

Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key></key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>X</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Y</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>X</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>X would like to access your camera to capture profile picture and class image.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>X would Like to access your location to show events going around you.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>X would Like to access your location to show events going around you.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>X would like to access your gallery to upload profile photo, class image, certificates and venue images.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Roboto-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Thin.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: share your info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

Add your Base Url Here

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <key>http://your.domian.paste.here</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: share your api request code

Comment: I just noticed that requests to production work (https) but not if I'm using staging (http). Could the difference between https and htttp be the issue?

Comment: ios do not allow HTTP requests. you have to add your HTTP domain in the info.plist file read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666142/how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-native-ios-application