# randomly fetch "The network connection was lost." in swift using "Alamofire.request"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Trying to call the web service as follows , and experiencing random "The network connection was lost" error causing app crash on device as well as simulator.

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["limit" : "3" , "offset" : self.storeArray?.count ?? 0], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):
```

my error bellow

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608000a5f950 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x60800029fea0 [0x1136c0df0]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x10020050a63e1c720000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://lokomart.com/services/getSearchResultData, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://lokomart.com/services/getSearchResultData, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.})
```

**// I have using php backend with godaddy deluxe hosting.**

**and also working with swift 3**

Comment: Do you see the issue on devices or on simulator only?

Comment: yes issue fetching with device and simulator.

Comment: did you get the resolution ? Its very random with my code as well, on both device and simulator

Comment: issue not resolve.
if you have any idea then suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this issue , I have tried increasing PHP backend processing timeout to 60 sec also tried changing Apache server timeout to 600 from 300, it only reduces the frequency , not best solution I think is to catch the failure and then either recreate the request and send it or just stop do something else.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["limit" : "3" , "offset" : self.storeArray?.count ?? 0], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
         break;
        case .failure(_ let error): {
         //redo all the work or stop 
         break;
         }
```

or what I am doing is as follows

```
if(response.result.isFailure) {
     print("Error occured")
     if(self.retryCounter! < 2) {                    
         self.retryCounter! += 1
         //recreating post request and sending again
          return
     }
     else {
         return
     }
}
```

Above code does the job well.
Notice that I edited your code and added "validate" method, without which some of the result data doesn't get updated, like "isFailure" property is always false.
I hope this gets you through the issue.

Comment: @user3091160 it's a bug can't help

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue and spend more than 1 week to fix this.
AND
i just **solved** this issue by changing **Wifi** connection.

Comment: Cool solution :)

Comment: OMG!  That worked!  Thanks.  Spent many hours debugging swift code thinking it was my fault.

Comment: @bauhaus9 sounds great.

Comment: Update:  I have two wifi networks.  The reaso I could NOT connect to my target host was because I had a network rule that was blocking any connectivity to that target host.  On the wifi network where it DID work, I had a clean, unblocked connection.  Once I fixed the rule on the misbehaving network, both networks allowed access. So, my code was fine, it was the network!

Answer (score 1):

Today, i had the same error. And i remember the property added for apple into iOS 9 `NSAppTransportSecurity`. You can try disable only for test, adding this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

You can to do this configuration better following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623388/2711766

Comment: Your application won't get to the AppStore with that code

Comment: Above solution isn't for random issues reported.