# POST method issues in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a form for user. After filling it, the user clicks the submit button and its data is submitted to server. I'm getting an issue that I get response null but my data from the form is successfully submitted to server. I don't know where the issue is coming. I want to run another function if response comes true. My code is this:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSString *urlLinkA=@"My URL";


    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlLinkA];

    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Parameter];


    NSLog(@"parameter %@",parameters);
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           [_indicator stopAnimating];
                                                           _indicator.hidden=YES;
                                                           NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);

                                                           NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                                                           NSLog(@"DDD %@",dictionary);

                                                           NSString *userid = [dictionary valueForKey:@"property_id"];
                                                           NSLog(@"UserID: %@", userid);



                                                           NSLog(@"Response: %@", dictionary);

                                                           if ([dictionary isEqual:@""]) {
                                                               [self Images];
                                                           }

                                                           HomePageViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
                                                           [self.navigationController pushViewController:presales animated:YES];

                                                           NSString *msg=@"Successfully Registered";

                                                           UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                                                                                          message:msg
                                                                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                                                           [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                                                           int duration = 2; // duration in seconds

                                                           dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                               [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                           });

                                                       }];


    NSLog(@"network error :");
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: are you added the NSTransport security in your app

Comment: yes. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: what the result you get here `NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
`

Comment: its (null). and data submit to server fine. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Why are you not printing the error message?

Comment: NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error); I'm writing this. @Sulthan

Comment: Is this url correct NSString *urlLinkA=@"My URL"; ?Please check

Comment: So, what is the error message?

Comment: Add NSTransportSecurity in your plist file https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623388/5842579

Comment: Bro, i have added it and thats why my data is going to server other than that it would not go. @NikolayKhramchenko

Comment: i had just write here My URL , i have used my url there this is not the issue. @user1000

Comment: Please try with postman or RestClient in your browser and debug your post request, it might be possible that server is not sending you proper response.

Comment: error also comes (null).@Sulthan

Comment: Let me check there. But how it is submitting the data? @Pankaj

Comment: simply create one post request which is you are sending to server and pass these parameter and URL in restClient or post man extension which you need to install in your browser and then check the response. you will get status 200 when your server accept request and sends  you proper response.

Comment: yeah now i get it, Thanks a lot. @Pankaj

Comment: make ur statement as an answer so that i could upvote it. @Pankaj

Comment: happy to help you @HamzaImran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with postman or RestClient in your browser and debug your post request, it might be possible that server is not sending you proper response. you can download it from https://restlet.com here.