# Swift 3 HTTPS GET Request

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https

Hi iam trying to do a get request from a HTTPS url. But iam continously getting the error.

> ```
> 2017-10-13 18:13:43.372427+0800 VQ Smart Home[13412:2155414] Unknown class _TtC13VQ_Smart_Home16ManageUserstable in Interface
> ```
>
> Builder file.
>       2017-10-13 18:13:43.403238+0800 VQ Smart Home[13412:2155471] TIC SSL Trust Error [6:0x604000167680]: 3:0
>       2017-10-13 18:13:43.403672+0800 VQ Smart Home[13412:2155471] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>       2017-10-13 18:13:43.404000+0800 VQ Smart Home[13412:2155471] Task <8BB05664-B56E-41CA-92F7-BBAECC8008E3>.<5> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -1202 [3:-9813])
>       2017-10-13 18:13:43.404496+0800 VQ Smart Home[13412:2155472] Task <8BB05664-B56E-41CA-92F7-BBAECC8008E3>.<5> finished with error - code:
>   -1202
>       error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a
>   server that is pretending to be “202.73.46.176” which could put your
>   confidential information at risk."
>   UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to
>   connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
>           ""
>       ), NSUnderlyingError=0x60400025c920 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
>           ""
>       )}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “202.73.46.176” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://202.73.46.176/api/v1/user/find/all/1,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://202.73.46.176/api/v1/user/find/all/1,
>   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0})

**ViewdidLoad**

```
let urlstr: String = "https://202.73.46.176/api/v1/user/find/all/1"

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlstr)! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let postString = ""
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    print("response = \(response)")

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

**Method**

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        //Implementation 1: VERY WEAK METHOD
        /*if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0{
         completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
         }else{
         completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
         }*/

        //Implementation 2:
        var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling
        var credential:URLCredential?

        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
            //certificate-based server credentials are used when verifying the server’s identity
            credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)

            if (credential != nil) {
                disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
            }
            else{
                disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling
            }
        }
        else{
            disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge
        }
        print("==============", #function,"  disposition: ", disposition)
        print("==============", #function,"  disposition: ", credential!)

        //completionHandler(disposition, credential);




        //Implementation 3:
        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        let certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust!, 0)

        // Set SSL policies for domain name check
        let policies = NSMutableArray();
        policies.add(SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, (challenge.protectionSpace.host as CFString)))
        SecTrustSetPolicies(serverTrust!, policies);

        // Evaluate server certificate
        var result = SecTrustResultType(rawValue: 0)!
        SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust!, &result)

        let isServerTrusted:Bool = (result == SecTrustResultType.unspecified || result == SecTrustResultType.unspecified || result == SecTrustResultType.proceed)
        print("==============",#function,"  isServerTrusted: ", isServerTrusted)
        print("==============", #function,"  result: ", result.hashValue,"  SecTrustResultType.unspecified: ", SecTrustResultType.unspecified.hashValue,"  SecTrustResultType.proceed: ", SecTrustResultType.proceed.hashValue)
        var certName = ""
//        if self.isSimulatingCertificateCorruption {
//            certName = corruptedCert
//        } else {
//            certName = cert
//        }

        // Get local and remote cert data
        let remoteCertificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate!) as Data
        let pathToCert            = Bundle.main.path(forResource: certName, ofType: "der")
        let localCertificate      = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToCert!))
        print(" remoteCertificateData: ", remoteCertificateData,"       localCertificate: ", localCertificate, "       serverTrust: ", serverTrust.debugDescription  )

        if ( remoteCertificateData == localCertificate) { //TODO:- this is strictly for tesing puposes, to allow untrusted severs. REMOVE IN PRODUCTION.
            let credential:URLCredential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust!)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        }else if (isServerTrusted && (remoteCertificateData == localCertificate)) {
            let credential:URLCredential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust!)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to fix this tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better answer..

Create a **SecurityCertificateManager**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


class SecurityCertificateManager {
    static let sharedInstance = SecurityCertificateManager()

    let defaultManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "12.3.3.3": .disableEvaluation
        ]

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: configuration,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }()
}
```

and call it like this

```
        let service = CommanLinksUtility().getServiceAuthUrl()
        let ticket = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "servicket") as! String
        let baseUrl = "https://12.3.3.3:5051/api/v1/user/find/all/1"
        let header = [ "content-type" : "application/json", "url": service,  "ticket" : ticket ]

      SecurityCertificateManager.sharedInstance.defaultManager.request(baseUrl, method: .get, parameters: header as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: header)
            .responseJSON { response in
                let jsonResult = JSON(data: response.data!)
                for anItem in jsonResult["result"].arrayValue {

                }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because your server doesn't have an SSL certificate, hence it's not trusted

"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “202.73.46.176” which could put your confidential information at risk."`

This part of the error alone should be enough to understand what's going on. Once you install a proper valid certificate that is trusted the error should go away. You can also have this be ignored by specifying it in your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But I would refrain from doing this and just getting an SSL certificate for your server

Referenced from [How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file) for the .plist keys

Answer (score -1):

You can use AFNETWorking or Almofire library