# Dispatch is not defined in thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-ios

I get the above error when I try and dispatch the action `isLoading` and `hasErrored`

```
export function fetchCategories() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        Promise.all([fetchPage(1), fetchPage(2)]).then(
            data => {
                dispatch(isLoading(false));
                dispatch(
                    fetchSuccessCategories([
                        ...data[0].categories,
                        ...data[1].categories
                    ])
                );
            },
            err => {
                dispatch(isLoading(false));
                dispatch(hasErrored(true));
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const initialState = {
    hasErrored: false,
    isLoading: true,
    isLoadingCredentials: true,
    fetchEvents: {},
    fetchCategories: []
};

const reduxLogger = createLogger();

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxLogger)
);

export default store;
```

// fetch categories

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./config/configureStore";

import AppNavigation from "./navigation";
import { fetchCategories } from "./actions/events";

// dispatch action to get array of events for app
store.dispatch(fetchCategories());

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppNavigation />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: `fetch` Network error, trying to update `NSAppTransportSecurity` `info.plist`, how can I do it without `xcode`?:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Did you correctly apply the redux-thunk middleware to your store?

Comment: yes i think so, added to question

Comment: Where do you use this `fetchCategories`? Can we see that component also?

Comment: No errors on windows/android, just iOS

Comment: Platform depended? Weird.

Comment: might be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file