# Not Secure HTTP connect swift

Tags: swift, apache, http, https

Is it possible somehow to connect to my apache server using swift without a HTTPS connection?

I want to make an application that fetch data from MySQL Database and parse them to JSON,I've done it, but when I try to use my ip address, swift does not parse my json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you need to add the proper keys to your Info.plist file to disable App Transport Security.

- [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)
- [How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file/31629980#31629980)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33