# React native axios with Authoriztion header is returning 400

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I recently implement Axios in my react native app. The problem I am facing is whenever I add authorization header with the request, it returns 400 while the same request with same Auth token is working fine with Postman. What can be the issue?

```
axios.get(EndPointURL, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: BearerToken
        }
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(
            reason
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that BearerToken is the same as the token you're using in PostMan? Seems to me you need you're not adding `Bearer` prefix that's required by OAuth2

Example:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${BearerToken}`
}
```

Comment: I am adding Bearer before the token, thats how postman works as well :). Yes same token in both othwise it should throw 401 error not 400.

Comment: try it this way `headers: { common: { authorization: BearerToken }  }`

Comment: Tried but did not work "Error: Request failed with status code 400"

Comment: Are you developing on iOS? And is your endpoint running over HTTPS or not?

Comment: Yes, i am running the build on iOS and no its over simple HTTP.

Comment: Your issue is App Transport Security, iOS is blocking your request because you're not using HTTPS, you need to add exception in your info.plist and then rebuild the app. Check that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623388/5200782

Comment: Will try it and let you know soon. Thanks for the help bro.

Comment: Actually before modifying the info.plist,  i tried to run the build on Android and its returning with the same 400 error. So i think the issue is something else than what you thought, am i right?