# App transport Security load Error even after adding it

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, ios13, app-transport-security

1. Even after adding **App Transport Security Settings** and **Allow Arbitrary Loads** under it I'm still getting the same error -

"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load
since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's
Info.plist file."

2. **also couldn't figure out why the value of 'App Transport Security Settings' on the right side of the table is showing 0**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` inside `App Transport Security Settings` dictionary, like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: This is a lazy approach.  It is better to add exceptions at a domain level than to completely disable ATS altogether for your app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623388/3708242  We still do not know when Apple is going to enforce the need to a justification for ATS exceptions, but many apps that completely disable ATS are going to be in for a rude awakening.  Also, using non-TLS connections put your users at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the above (yes it does still work at time of writing). For development purposes this works, but you won't be able to publish beyond 100 users in your Test Flight.

If you intend to push the app to the public or a Beta group you'll need to move to HTTPS or have very good reasons for the HTTP. See more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).