# How to get all keys in json object in swift

Tags: swift

i have JSON object like below

```
{
"a":"123",
"b":"testing"
}
```

In java i am using `JSONObject.names()` method.

```
JSONArray keys = jsonObject.names();
```

And result getting like this `["a","b"]`;

Similar result how to get in swift?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself and why are you working with swift 3, it's obsolete by now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`JSONSerialization`** to parse the JSON `data` into a `Dictionary` of type `[String:Any]` and then use `keys` to get all the key strings from it.

```
do {
    if let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] {
        print(dict.keys)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = [String:Array<DataModel>]
```

where,

```
class DataModel {
    var name: String?     
}
```

and to fetch the keys and value,

```
for i in 0...(results.length-1){
    // To print the results keys
    print(results.keys[results.startIndex.advancedBy(i)])
    // To get value from that key
    let valueFromKeyCount = (results[results.keys[results.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]] as Array<DataModel>).count
    for j in 0...(valueFromKeyCount-1) {
         let dm = results[results.keys[results.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]][j] as DataModel
         print(dm.name) 
    }
}
```

Your question is already answered here - [How to fetch the key from JSON in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564412/how-to-fetch-the-key-from-json-in-swift)

Comment: i have dynamic json ..how to return array of string from method

Comment: Your loops are pretty cumbersome. In Swift there is `for (key, value) in results`. And there is also `for i in 0..<results.length`