# how can i pass a javascript object from javascript to iOS swift?

Tags: swift

I am wondering how can I pass object from `Javascript` to `swift`.
I don't know which type should i declare the variable in order to receive the javascript object.

the following is my `Javascript` code to create an object

```
var labs = ["dead","sfdsf","DH-dsfdsfds","DH-sdfdsf"]
var labgrp = {labGrp:"R", labGrpDesc:"fdgfdg",labs:labs}
var labGroups = []
labGroups[0] = labgrp
var labGroup = {labGroups}
```

how can I pass **labGroup** to `swift`? By using `JSON`??
Please comment it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i pass labGroup to swift? By using JSON??

### YES

Best option to you is **JSON .**

Pass JSON from `Javascript` and catch it in `Swift`

---

### EDIT

#### see this for [converting Javascript object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

```
var j={"name":"binchen"};
JSON.stringify(j);
```

**Note:** download js for above code to work [path](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: how can i convert labGroup object to JSON in javascript?? i am new in programming. thank you

Comment: i have raised other question for receiving the json from javascript   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558381/swift-step-to-receive-json-object-from-javascript              could you please kindly help?

Comment: And also, how to handle it after passing to swift

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift

Comment: the example is showing how to handle the json. however, after stringify, it becomes jsvalue in swift

Comment: i try to use todictionary() but fail