# Can't access json value returned from PHP script

Tags: ios, json, swift

My PHP script returns response like

```
Optional({
    message = "";
    response =     {
        "session_id" = mf6pnrsf931m96g0hc3n4pjbw3;
        "session_name" = d72d1363f44031cac4148b0e6fa789d6;
    };
    "session_valid" = true;
    success = true;
})
```

How can I access/print the value of session id/session name in Swift 2.2?
I dont have any problem in storing the value returned by 'session_valid'

Comment: This format is called JSON. Google `Swift parse JSON`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift)

Comment: No, no..I am able to access 'the_message' from the data, but I dont know how to print 'value1' or 'value2'

Comment: So you already have Swift code accessing the data? Can you show it?

Comment: See this..I know how this works.. var json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

if let parseJSON = json {

         message = parseJSON[“message"] as? String
}

Comment: key1 and key2 are actually 2 parameters which the response field is returning..i dont know how to access them

Comment: @FGala you need to edit the question and put your code there in proper formatting.

Comment: Read the Apple article [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37). It's for Swift 3 but you can learn the proposed procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was this-

```
let response = objectDic.objectForKey("response") as? NSDictionary
```

followed by

```
let session_name = response.objectForKey("session_name") as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     var parseObject: AnyObject?

    let data = NSData() //response data that you get from script(use this instead of "data"). if response is string then you need to convert the string to data


    do{
        parseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }

    let objectDic = parseObject as! NSDictionary

    if let status = objectDic.objectForKey("success") as? Bool  {
        if status == true {
            if let validSession = objectDic.objectForKey("session_valid") as? Bool{

                if validSession {
                    let response = objectDic.objectForKey("response") as? NSDictionary

                    print(response)
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That doesn’t really seem to address the OP’s situation, though. Can you edit it to parse the specific bits they need? They already know how to parse JSON in general.

Comment: @AsaduzzamanShuvro..your answer led me to what i needed..thank u:)