# IOS: POST Array values to JSON Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, dictionary

I have an array in this form:

```
(
        {
        itemId = 18;
        itemPrice = "90.00";
        itemQuantity = 100;
    },
        {
        itemId = 17;
        itemPrice = "88.00";
        itemQuantity = 120;
    }
)
```

I have to post it to Json server in this form

```
im[18][price]=90
im[18][stock]=100
im[18][check]=1

im[17][price]=88
im[17][stock]=120
im[17][check]=1
```

Please help me how to do this currently i am using the following code

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < selectedIdArray.count; i++)
    {
        mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6&menu_name=%@&im[%@][price]=%@&im[%@][stock]=%@&im[%@][check]=%@",MenuNameStr,selectedIdArraySTR,selectedPriceArraySTR,selectedIdArraySTR,selectedQuantityArraySTR,selectedIdArraySTR,@"1"];
    }
```

and it gives the following response

```
map data api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6&menu_name=&im[18,17][price]=90.00,88.00&im[18,17][stock]=100,120&im[18,17][check]=1
```

Please someone help me out to send the following data separately to the server

Comment: What is your question exactly? You do a POST? Then don't you put that data into HTTPBody?

Comment: same thing i dont know hot to break an array. please help me to send saperate data for saperate parameters. currently it takes full array for parameter

Comment: The second format you have shown is not JSON.

Comment: please help me to sort out this issue how i post this array

Comment: Can you tell me how do you want to post the data?
what will be the actual url or request?

Comment: i want to send data in this form im[18][price]=90
im[18][stock]=100
im[18][check]=1

im[17][price]=88
im[17][stock]=120
im[17][check]=1   but currently it send in this type im[18,17][price]=90.00,88.00&im[18,17][stock]=100,120&im[18,17][check]=1

Comment: Ok will post it in some time.

Comment: Post your full code with your url.I will help you.

Comment: @Abhi check out my answer and let me know if you have any issue with it. I tested it and it works fine here.

Comment: ok i am trying this code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this as your dict.

```
{
    itemId = 17;
    itemPrice = "88.00";
    itemQuantity = 120;
}
```

first get the count of elements in dict.

```
int getKeysCount = [allKeys count];
```

Assuming this to be the output you need

```
im[18][price]=90
im[18][stock]=100
im[18][check]=1

im[17][price]=88
im[17][stock]=120
im[17][check]=1
```

you need to update your loop

```
mapData = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"api_key=XX--XX&menu_name=%@"];

for (int i = 0; i < selectedIdArray.count; i++) {
    int k = itemId[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < getKeysCount.count; i++) {
        mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&im[k][price]=%@&im[k][stock]=%@&im[k][check]=%@",itemPrice[i],itemQuantity[i],@"1"];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",mapData);

//Let me know if you find any query in this answer
```

Comment: what is itemId[i] here array or string?

Comment: I am assigning  itemId = 17 as int k = itemId[i];

Comment: but i have 2 item id

Comment: man its inside a loop, it will automatically get updated, that's why i put  itemId[i].

Comment: @Abhi Did my answer fix your issue?

Comment: actually i have two values in itemid (17,18 as array) which may be increase or decrease and i am not able to break that array

Comment: that is why i put this line inside the loop
`int k = itemId[i];`
This will iterate as per the the array count to get different itemId.

Comment: itemId = 17 as int k = itemId[i]; not working i have to store an array as itemId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147156/discussion-between-abhi-and-iuser).

Comment: let me know when you are online

Answer (score -2):

I think you want JSON Parse from file 
Here **Swift JSON Parse**
[How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift)
And **Objective-C Parse**
[How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)