# converting Array of dictionaries into array of objects

Tags: ios, swift

i have a string of this form:

```
[{"LocationsItems":[{"ItemId":4,"LocationId":3,"Qty":34},{"ItemId":19,"LocationId":3,"Qty":55}]}];
```

i need to convert this to an array of object, i tried this:

```
let data = convertedData.data(using: .utf8)!
        do {
            if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
            {
                print(jsonArray)

            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

and returned this , which is an array of dictionaries:

```
[["LocationsItems": <__NSArrayI 0x600003a1c100>(
{
    ItemId = 4;
    LocationId = 3;
    Qty = 34;
},
{
    ItemId = 19;
    LocationId = 3;
    Qty = 55;
}
)
]]
```

how can i extract the objects from it?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift)

Comment: its not the same

Comment: MrJ why you want to convert, tell us the purpose of conversion?

Comment: How do you know that ? @MrJ

Comment: I suggest you to don't use array dictionary. Use struct or class with codable your answer is  you just have to write one line `if let objects =   jsonArray["LocationsItems"] as? [[String:Any]]`

Comment: i want to display the values in a tableview

Comment: @MrJ - see answer below.

Comment: if you mean the answer of Andrei Durnea, it didnt work

Comment: I've updated the response, it conforms yo tour structure now @MrJ, it should work now

Answer (score 2):

You can create a struct of `LocationItem`.

```
struct LocationItem {
    var itemId: Int?
    var locationId: Int?
    var qty: Int?    
}

var innerDictionary = jsonArray[0] as? [String: Any]
var arrayOfDict = innerDictionary["LocationsItems"] as? [[String: Any]]

var locationsItems = arrayOfDict.map { 
    LocationItem(itemId: $0["ItemId"], locationId: $0["LocationId"], qty: $0["Qty"]) 
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `Codable`:

```
struct LocationItem: Codable {
    var itemId: Int?
    var locationId: Int?
    var qty: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemId = "ItemId"
        case locationId = "LocationId"
        case qty = "Qty"
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let responseStructure = try decoder.decode([[String:[[String:Any]]]], from: data)
} catch {
    // failed
}

let locationItems = responseStructure[0]["LocationsItems"]
```

Comment: Are you using Codeable or not?

Comment: then, I guess it's ok if you use the 1st option provided

Comment: i tried it, it didnt work , it gave the following output: LocationItem(itemId: nil, locationId: nil, qty: nil)]

Comment: I see now your structure better, updating the response now.

Comment: @MrJ Does the arrayOfDict load? I mean does it have anything relevant after it passes the line of its declaration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182333/discussion-between-andrei-durnea-and-mrj).

Comment: if you print innerDictionary["LocationsItems"] what does output?