# hi guys need help, how could I parse this response with swift alamofire

Tags: swift, parsing, alamofire, jsonresponse

I want to parse this JSON response any help.

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "chef": 1,
  "user": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "username": "test",
        "user_email": "test@test.tn"
  },
  "post": {
       "id": 24,
       "lieu": "test",
       "date": "12/05/2018"
  }
}
```

Comment: share some code you have tried.

Comment: how do u want to parse like in class or struct . ?

Comment: This question has been asked a million times, please do some research. There are many articles/tutorials to read and similar questions here on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your json like following way :-

```
    //start loader
    Alamofire.request(yourURL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: yourHeader).responseJSON {
                 respo in

                 if respo.result.isSuccess {
                    // stop loader
                    let json = respo.result.value! as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                    let user = json["user"]as? [String:Any] ?? [:] //value of user key
                    let user_id = user["user_id"]as? String ?? "" //value of user_id key
                 } else {
                    // stop loader
                    print("Something went Wrong")
                 }
              }
```

pass your Header instead of `yourHeader`

I hope it will work for you ...:)